# Data source for pharmacy directory

Tags: data-request, usa, medical

Where can I find a reliable US national pharmacy database? I need basic info like name, address, if they are mail order, etc.

Does not have to be free.

Comment: Googling 'list of pharmacies site:.gov' (no quotes) yields links to several state lists; https://www.fda.gov/drugs/drugsafety/drugintegrityandsupplychainsecurity/ucm281446.htm may also be helpful as may https://www.fda.gov/drugs/resourcesforyou/consumers/buyingusingmedicinesafely/buyingmedicinesovertheinternet/besaferxknowyouronlinepharmacy/ucm318487.htm

Answer (score 1):

Medicare publishes a list on their open data platform of all pharmacies that participate in their program as well as the pharmacy's:

- Address
- Phone number
- Goods from Medicare it provides.

The dataset is available in data.medicare.gov [here](https://data.medicare.gov/Supplier-Directory/Supplier-Directory-Data/ct36-nrcq).